# %20 in URL in archive page shows error 404 on page

Tags: 404-error, custom-post-type-archives

I have made a custom archive page, so the page is working for single words like - **National** Category. For this the archive page works as it should be but when it comes to two words like - **Economy and Business**, now in this case the archive page shows error and the URL has **%20** which means space (searched on google). But why is the error 404 showing up ?

**http://mywebsite.com/category/Economy%20and%20Business** - This shows error 404
**http://mywebsite.com/category/National/** - This works

Comment: Without any further information this question is just an invitation for guessing, and the simplest guess is that (as rick says) you have nothing in that url. If that is not true you will need to edit the question and explain why do you think 404 is the wrong response.

Comment: These are not urls WordPress would create for page/post or category slugs, they get sanitized for exactly this reason. How did you create these and what should they display exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual URL that you are having difficulties with, it's hard to answer.

But, I suspect that the URL really **doesn't** exist. Which is why you get a '404' not found error.

If you edit your question to include the actual URL (put it in a 'code' block), you might get a more specific answer.

Comment: I have added the url structure but I cannot specify the exact URL. Can this help ?

Comment: Take a look at the Permalink shown on the page when you edit the page via the Admin, Pages interface. It may be that there are some unallowed characters in there, or it doesn't match the URL you posted. At worst case, copy the content from the page into a new page and use that new page instead.